# Create tag for only Fetched Data in Tag-it.js want validation for create tag of an any external data

Tags: javascript, jquery, tag-it

At the time of using Tag-it.js & css of it i fetched data using Ajax call, I want to create tags only from fetched data & don't want to create tag if user enter any of the external information outside the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of selecting tags(data fetched from database for that particular AutoComplete) you need to manage validation for the such kind of the requirement which will be handled through the one type of the tags array or data-model. So when you select any of the tag then its checks inside the array or data-model if entered tag is not exist inside the array or data-model then it should fire the validation.

Comment: Thanks Kishor for your support, I have already applied it a year ago as kendo validation. .. :)